# Error: An API error occurred: account_inactive

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I tried running `npm start` but I'm getting this error:

```
> nescafe@1.0.0 start
> node app

[INFO]  socket-mode:SocketModeClient:0 Going to establish a new connection to Slack ...
⚡️ Bolt app is running!
/home/kr/Workspace/nescafe/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:56
    const error = errorWithCode(new Error(`An API error occurred: ${result.error}`), ErrorCode.PlatformError);
                                ^

Error: An API error occurred: account_inactive
    at platformErrorFromResult (/home/kr/Workspace/nescafe/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:56:33)
    at WebClient.apiCall (/home/kr/Workspace/nescafe/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/WebClient.js:181:56)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
  data: { ok: false, error: 'account_inactive', response_metadata: {} }
}
```

How do I resolve it? I already checked my tokens and they are correct.
The app also runs when I try running it on another laptop. I also tried calling the auth.test as suggested in another stackoverflow question, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not post your token here on Stack Overflow, as it can be used maliciously.

The `account_inactive` error happens when using a bot token and the bot is uninstalled, or when the token is for a deleted user or workspace. If you reinstall your app, you should receive a new token and that should work.

Comment: forgot to remove it. lol. all good. it's a token to a workspace that i only made to test the app.